# Typing nested array of objects

Tags: typescript

How can I define `foo` so that i don't have to specify `as Constraint` for each of the 
array items ?

```
type Constraint = {
    constraint: 'required' | 'equal'
}


function bar<K extends string>(d: Record<K, Constraint[]>) {
    return Object.keys(d).reduce((a, b) => (a[b] = '', a),
                                 {} as { [key: string]: string }) as Record<K, string>
}

const foo = { apple: [ { constraint: 'required' } ] }
// Error  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"required" | "equal"'.
const baz = bar(foo)


// Works fine
const foo2 = { apple: [  { constraint: 'required' } as Constraint ] }
const baz2 = bar(foo2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type a string, TS recognizes it as a plain `string`, not like the `'required'` literal. You can:

1. Use the object literal directly in the function call:

```
const baz = bar({ apple: [ { constraint: 'required' } ] })
```

This way inference is preserved

2. Declare the string `as const`, i.e.:

```
const foo = { apple: [ { constraint: 'required' as const } ] }
```

This lets know TS that you don't mean a generic string but the exact literal you typed. In older TS version `as const` is not present buy you could still use `'required' as 'required'`